# Why does a USB-C connected monitor goes blank when an embedded HTML browser video starts playing?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I have a Latitude 7490 i7-8650U 32GB RAM Windows 10 system with 2 external HP 24es monitors.

The graphic card is Intel UHD Graphics 620. My resolution is set to 1920x1080.

I am using a [dual HDMI to USB-C adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0899HYCR3) from CLDAY. This linked one says GADEBAO but Amazon claims I purchased a different variation of it.

If I browse https://www.ctvnews.ca and the live coverage video starts playing then my USB-C connected monitor will go blank. I've tried this on Edge, Firefox and chrome and all do the same thing.  Youtube never causes an issue and using vlc player is also just fine.

The HTML seems to be a jasper-player

```
<div class="jasper-player-overlay__container--vXxZG">...
```

I've searched and there are many references to people having the same issue with different laptops and configurations reaching out to their manufacturer or the os support people who generally recommend updating drivers/BIOS/ and throwing salt over your shoulder. None of these ever seemed to have anyone achieve a solution.

Users have reported updating BIOS/drivers/switching USB-C adapters and not achieving a solution. The one user who reported some success switched from HDMI to DisplayPort. The back of my monitors only have HDMI or VGA.

Normally I have both monitors plugged into a 2x HDMI to USB-C dongle that goes into the USB-C port. In that configuration both monitors go blank when the video starts playing. Closing the browser tab with the video player allows the monitors to restore their video feeds.

Currently I have one monitor in the HDMI port and one in the dual HDMI to USB-C dongle. In this configuration only the USB-C monitor goes blank.

I've tried the power management setting and changing pci-express and the usb selective suspend settings to disabled on plugged in.  I've restart the laptop after doing this.

My current settings has the laptop display mirror monitor 1 and monitor 2 is extended.  I have changed it to just be the two external displays and blank out the laptop screen but that had no effect.

Comment: While I don´t have a definite answer for you, I suspect this may be because of HDCP, a mechanism which protects content that is shown over HDMI connections. DRM protection of the website (e.g. Widevine) may require a certain HDCP level and thus your monitor that does not support this goes blank. I would suggest checking whether HDCP is supported and enabled in your configuration

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe the dongle doesn't support HDCP.  The monitor and hdmi cables have to be fine since the cables and monitors are identical.  I'll see if I can search up any HDCP / usb-c issues.

Comment: This thread seems to reference HDCP errors with dongles. 
 I am going to order another dongle - amazon has one with a review that says netflix was fine and that is HDCP content so hopefully that will do the trick. 
 https://www.reddit.com/r/VIDEOENGINEERING/comments/bqql19/hdcp_errors_when_using_usbc_on_macbook_pro_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped the USB-C CLDAY for a [Selore & S-Global USB-C dongle](https://www.amazon.ca/Selore-S-Global-Converter-LenovoYoga-Thinkpad/dp/B07QKVY23Q) and everything works. No issues with the monitor dropping the feed! Glad I didn't waste my $30!

Thanks to @rrr for the HDCP hint!

[image: usbc to dual hdmi]